# Place Photoshop layer comps in Indesign

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, cs6, layer-composition

If you have an Indesign document you can place for example PNG's, PSD's, Ai artboards, etc in element place holders in the document. I wonder however if there's any way to also place Photoshop layer comps? It would be very useful since I have one Photoshop document depicting visuals with different states. However exporting these different states to PNG seems to be the only way of getting these in to Indesign, and then you have to make a new export for every update of the visuals... If the link could be done with layer comps instead it would make my life a whole lot easier!

Does anyone know if it's possible and then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a talk with a colleague visual designer who loooves layer comps, and he explained that it's really easy.

- You drag the PSD into you Indesign document, the default layer comp will be displayed
- Then you right click on the image, choose **Object Layer Options...**'
- There you'll have both a drop down with all your layer comps and also the layers/folders in the PSD

Comment: It's rare that I Google something, a design question, and find the perfect answer first result. In this case everything was pure magic. Thank you so much, layers working and sinking perfectly in my InDesign doc.

Comment: @Sara Hey Sara! Glad you found the answer you were looking for! Good luck with your design work! ;)